# Failed to connect to mailserver in wamp while using gmail as smtp server

Tags: php

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" port 465, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\send.php on line 18

And my php file is as follows:

```
<html>

  <head>
  <title>Sending HTML email using PHP</title>
  </head>

  <body>

      <?php
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
     $to = "sravya.siji@gmail.com";
     $subject = "Not using Gmail";

     $message = "<b>HTML message</b>";
     $message .= "<h1>Manu this is sent from PHP Code....</h1>";

     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message);

     if( $retval == true ) {
        echo "Message sent successfully...";
     }else {
        echo "Message could not be sent...";
     }
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Could you please help me in solving this error! ......Thanks at advance:)

Comment: It cannot work like that. When using SSL Google ( and others ) also expect a userid and password. You connot provide those using this method so the connection FAILS. Either install a mail server or use `phpMailer`. `phpMailer` is the simplest option!

Comment: Also you should not be putting your code into the `\wamp\www` Create a subfolder and then create a Virtual Host

Answer (score 0):

Did you try smtp-relay.gmail.com, which is the one recommended by Google on port 25?

Also, did you check if your server was able to communicate with it? Might be blocking somewhere..

Comment: That would be sending mail over an insecure connection